# VB Getting list of local users

Tags: vb.net, list, local

I need way of getting all local users. If i just go to the users folder ill get the local users and the domain users. Is there a way to get only the local users.

What i want is the name.

Comment: I havent triend anything. I know that i can access "C:\Users" and get the name of all users. But i only need the ones in the local machine, not in the domain. I need to know a way of doing this, im thinking maybe with regedit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices` to be able to use this function...

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Users As List(Of String) = GetLocalUsers("localhost")

    For Each User As String In Users
        MessageBox.Show(User)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GetLocalUsers(ByVal MachineName As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim WinNt As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" & MachineName)
    Dim UserList As New List(Of String)

    For Each User As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry In WinNt.Children
        If User.SchemaClassName = "User" Then
            UserList.Add(User.Name)
        End If
    Next

    Return UserList
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try it when i can :) Much apreciated

Comment: @Plutonix Yes i know, but i dont know if it solves my problem. When i am able to test it i will click the checkmark if it does solve it :D :D

Comment: It says its not declared, what imports should i use?

Comment: Its in my answer.. You need to add reference ... imports system.directoryservices...

Comment: Warning 1 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Directory.Services' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. ERROR MESSAGE  why is this showing this

Comment: Added the import ot the references still not working oO

Comment: Please see edit's. This is tried and tested; I was able to pull back all user's during my test.

Comment: Thank you that helped. Sorry for the trouble.