# getting windows user account (profiles) list

Tags: windows, vb.net

I'm trying to take names of all windows user accounts. my code is working but it prints unnecessary user account also,

here is the code I'm using,

```
Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount")
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
For Each envVar As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
    Console.WriteLine(envVar("Name"))
Next
```

Output:

```
Administrator
DefaultAccount
Guest
Sam
WDAGUtilityAccount
```

`Sam` is the only user account I created on this PC. I can assume `Administrator` and `Guest` accounts come as default with windows. But `DefaultAccount` and `WDAGUtilityAccount` accounts are extremely unnecessary for printing in here.  How can I prevent those unnecessary accounts printing from this code

Comment: workgroup or domain?

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993947/vb-getting-list-of-local-users ?

Comment: @Devcon My Pc connected into a domain but tested on workgroup got the same result

Comment: @Devcon tried with that answer but it freezes the UI and nothing happen.

Comment: i am at work, connected to a domain, it worked perfectly, do you have any additional code in there? can you try it alone in a new project and see if it works?

Comment: [Win32_UserAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount) has properties you can query along the main class. See: `AccountType`, `SIDType`, `Domain`, `LocalAccount` etc.. Combine as needed.

Comment: @Jimi that will be a solution. I will try on that.

Answer (score 0):

As the Jimi's suggestion, I have updated my code by using `Disabled` property.

[Win32_UserAccount class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount)

```
Dim query As New SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount")
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
For Each envVar As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
   If Not envVar("Disabled").ToString.ToUpper.Equals("TRUE") Then
       Console.WriteLine(envVar("Name"))
   End If
Next
```